# Cordova track.stop() not releasing "In-Call" volume mode

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, crosswalk

I have an issue with sound output on android (Galaxy S7 edge + crosswalk):

Before my call when I try to change the sound I can set the "ringtone" volume:

[image: Before call, I can change Ringtone volume]

Then I'm starting a webrtc audio call with

```js
const constraints = {
  video: false,
  audio: true,
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                      .then(stream => this.stream = stream)
```

I can change the call volume by pressing the volume buttons:

[image: During call volume can be changed]

Then I'm ending it by calling

```js
this.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
   track.stop();
});
```

But the sound is still "In-Call" :

[image: After call volume is still In-Call]

When I close the app, I can change ringtone again...

What's wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: We thought we had a fix but it came again. Quiet weird. You should try to play with the audio modes (in native Java code)...

Comment: This does not seem to happen when disabling echoCancellation:
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: { echoCancellation: false }});`

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your 'ending' code. **Just make sure `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` called only once or all tracks stopped before it called again**.